# Is there a way to boot from a USB on a MacBook Pro with disc drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I know that on certain models of MacBook you can only install Windows from the SuperDrive—is there a way to circumvent this limitation? My computer is a MacBook Pro 13" from 2010, it doesn't have a disc drive and I want it to boot from a USB with Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Windows 7 with Bootcamp on OS X Yosemite with USB Key](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168808/install-windows-7-with-bootcamp-on-os-x-yosemite-with-usb-key) or [Install Windows 7 on MacBook Pro via USB?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55654/install-windows-7-on-macbook-pro-via-usb)

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you hear the boot chime, hold the Option or Alt key.

Some icons should appear. Be patient if they don't appear immediately (but if after an entire minute the screen stays white there could be a problem). If it simply boots into OS X, you might have pressed the Option key too late.

There should be a hard drive icon for every partition on your hard disk and a USB drive icon for your external drive. Click on the desired boot medium and click the arrow under the icon or use the arrow keys and press enter after selecting the boot medium you want.

Comment: Some older Mac models are restricted to install Windows from the internal Super Drive. So holding opt/alt at the "right" time will not solve the problem of the OP.

Comment: I'll wait for the Peer Pressure badge then...